# How to apply a decorator to subroutines in python

Tags: python, decorator, subroutine

I want to modify the way several of my functions behave, so the use of a decorator comes to mind.  For example let's say I have a batch data taking function `takeData(s)`:

```
def takeData(s):
    takeDataSet_1(s)
    takeDataSet_2(s)
    .
    .
    .
```

A simple thing that I might want to do is update the parameter dict s, before each of the takeDataSet function calls.  So that the effective code would be more like this:

```
def takeData(s):
    s = updateParams(s)
    takeDataSet_1(s)
    s = updateParams(s)
    takeDataSet_2(s)
    s = updateParams(s)
    .
    .
    .
```

Is there a way to do this with a decorator so that my code would look more like

```
@takeDataWithUpdatedParams
def takeData(s):
    takeDataSet_1(s)
    takeDataSet_2(s)
```

Is there a way to control the depth of recursion such a decorator?  So that if takeDataSet_1(s) had subroutines of its own s could be updated between them, as in:

```
@recursiveUpdateParams
def takeData(s):
    takeDataSet_1(s)
    takeDataSet_2(s)

def takeDataSet_1(s):
    takeData_a(s)
    takeData_b(s)
```

Gets executed as

```
def takeData(s):
    s = updateParams(s)
    takeDataSet_1(s)
    s = updateParams(s)
    takeDataSet_2(s)
    s = updateParams(s)

def takeDataSet_1(s):
    s = updateParams(s)
    takeData_a(s)
    s = updateParams(s)
    takeData_b(s)
```

Comment: No, a decorator cannot alter the body of the function itself. It can influence the inputs (the arguments) when called, and what is returned, but not what goes on inside. The same applies to further calls.

Comment: Is there an alternative that can alter the body?

Comment: You'll have to parse the source into an Abstract Syntax Tree, then transform that tree. In essence, you'd have to use tools to rewrite the function. See the [`ast` module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/ast.html), but this is not for the faint of heart.

Comment: @Canaryyellow: The thing is that altering the body is much harder to get right.  If the function is doing anything else with `s`, it can difficult to know whether you can safely mess with it in between the other stuff that it's used for.

Comment: @Canaryyellow If you're asking that kind of question, refactor your code.  Also, Python (fortunately) is not FORTRAN so there's not `SUBROUTINE` ;)

Comment: @CongMa, the reason I was hoping this approach would be easier than refactoring is that the takeData and takeDataSet_1 etc are often group library code that I don't really want to modify.  This type of change would probably not get approved for merge into master and I don't want to have to deal with a painful merging process when I pull master every couple of days.  I thought a minor mod to my client side code would be easier... guess not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Very interesting question. To achieve this, you need to dive deep into the function object (without `eval`, `exec` or `ast` stuff, anyway).

```
def create_closure(objs):
    creat_cell = lambda x: (lambda: x).__closure__[0]
    return tuple(create_cell(obj) for obj in objs)
```

```
def hijack(mapper):
    from types import FunctionType
    def decorator(f):
        globals_ = {k: mapper(v) for k, v in f.__globals__.items()}
        closure_ = f.__closure__
        if closure_:
            closure_ = create_closure(i.cell_contents for i in closure_)
        return (lambda *arg, **kwarg:
                FunctionType(f.__code__, globals_, f.__name__,
                             f.__defaults__, closure_)(*arg, **kwarg))
    return decorator
```

Test:

```
x = 'x'
y = 'y'
@hijack(lambda obj: 'hijacked!' if obj is x else obj)
def f():
    return (x, y)
f()
```

Out:

```
('hijacked!', 'y')
```

Finally a solution to the original problem:

```
x = lambda: 'x()'
y = lambda: 'y()'
mydecorator = lambda f: lambda *arg, **kwarg: f(*arg, **kwarg) + ' decorated!'
targets = {id(x): mydecorator(x)}
def mapper(obj):
    if id(obj) in targets:
        return targets[id(obj)]
    else:
        return obj
@hijack(mapper)
def f():
    return (x(), y())
f()
```

Out:

```
('x() decorated!', 'y()')
```

Comment: Wow, this is exactly what I wanted to learn!  So cool.  Thanks a lot, this helps me solve a whole class of problems that I have.

Answer (score 1):

No.  Decorators wrap a function, which means they can add their own behavior before and after the function.  They can't change what happens "in the middle" of the function, as your example does (let alone what happens in the middle of other functions called by that function, as in your recursion example).

You could create a decorator-like function that accepts your `takeData_*` functions as arguments and does the updating, so you'd do something like:

```
def updateAndCall(func, params):
    s = updateParams(params)
    func(s)

def takeData(s):
    updateAndCall(takeData_1, s)
    updateAndCall(takeData_2, s)
```

However, whether this will be useful depends on the interaction between the various functions.  In particular, with this approach each "update" happens to the original `s`; the updates are not cumulative with the updated `s` being updated again for the second call, etc.